# Error conforming to a self made protocol in Swift

Tags: ios, delegates, swift, protocols, xcode6

I've created a protocol in one of my ViewControllers above the class declaration like so:

```
@class_protocol protocol CRAAddCredentialDelegate {
    func didAddCredential()
}

class CRAAddCredentialTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    ....
}
```

However, when I try to conform to this protocol:

```
class CRAMainViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, CRAAddCredentialDelegate {
    ....
}
```

I get an error:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you added the function `didAddCredential()` to your `CRAMainViewController` class?

By adding the `, CRAAddCredentialDelegate` to the list of protocols, you're indicating that your class will provide all of the variables and functions that protocol includes.

So you need to actually provide them.

```
class CRAAddCredentialTableViewController: UITableViewController {
     func didAddCredential() {
         // add code here
     }

     ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should implement the required protocol. In your case  `func didAddCredential()` declared in the protocol `CRAAddCredentialDelegate` is not implemented , so its giving error.